# How to upload file via camera in webview which opens via Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a chatbot on Facebook Messenger and in between my flows I need to open a webview where the user can upload a file. Now, I want an option to come up which allows the user to upload an image via the camera or gallery when he clicks on the below `input` tag. As show in the [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1k1d.jpg). This works fine when the same page opens in Chrome browser.

```
<input id="upload-btn-id-se" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" capture="camera">
```

Problem is that in when the same webpage opens in Webview via Facebook Messenger it directly redirects me to the document/gallery app.

How can I get the option to upload via camera in the webview?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've noticed that Chrome's webview doesn't media capture via the camera. Refer [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#hardware_sensors).